# Finding dimensions of a Path2D

Tags: javascript, canvas

In a project of mine I'm drawing a bunch of custom `Path2D` shapes onto a `Canvas`. Since I need it to be extensible, to be able to do stuff like perform hit detection on them, and interact with other elements, I need to be able to detect the size of a given `Path2D`.

As far as I can tell there's no way to do this through `Path2D`'s interface (yet, it's still experimental), does anyone know how I might achieve this, short of requiring the user to specify the width and length themselves when subclassing my class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hit detection, you can use `context.isPointInPath`.

You're correct about Path2D total lengths & bounding boxes...

There's no native Path2D (or html5 canvas) method like SVG's `.getTotalLength` or `.getPointAtLength`. Therefore, to calculate total length or bounding boxes you'll have to calculate points along each component of the path.

You probably know (or can Google) that the line has a simple geometric solution to calculate length & bounds given the starting and ending points on the line segment. And the arc has an equally simple geometric arc-length calculation and a simple trigonometric solution to plot points given the center point, radius and the beginning / ending arc angles. **Hint:** an arc's bounds can be calculated by finding the minimum & maximum x,y values of: the arc's centerpoint and any existing point on the arc at 0, 90, 180 & 270 degrees.

Bezier curves are a bit harder to plot, so here's a **hint:** Cubic Bezier curves can be plotted using De Casteljau's algorithm. Quadratic Bezier curves can also be plotted using De Casteljau's algorithm--just set the 2 middle control points equal to each other and a Cubic Bezier curve becomes a Quadratic Bezier curve. This is a "brute force" method but a fairly accurate measurement can be obtained by sampling as few as 20 intervals along the curve.

If your design requirements allow more rough approximates, then you will find that cubic Bezier curves are always contained within their control points.

If you're more mathematically inclined, you can also use first derivative roots to more directly calculate the bounds of Bezier curves. For more information, there is an *excellent* treatise on Bezier Curves here: http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately supporting arbitrary shapes might mean I'll have to fall back on basic bounding boxes (for now).